# VBScript to export selected portion of Excel sheet to a PDF, on one page

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, vbscript

I currently have a VBScript that exports an entire excel worksheet to a PDF. I was wondering if it would be possible to set the script to only export the selected areas. I know this can be done manually, but I've been tasked with automating this process. If achieved, it would make the whole reporting proccess a lot easier. The VBScript that I'm currently using is:

```
Sub PDFActiveSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String
Dim myFile As Variant
Dim strFile As String
On Error GoTo errHandler

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder
strFile = Replace(Replace(ws.Name, " ", ""), ".", "_") _
            & "_" _
            & Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd\_hhmm") _
            & ".pdf"
strFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFile

myFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
    (InitialFileName:=strFile, _
        FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf", _
        Title:="Select Folder and FileName to save")

If myFile <> "False" Then
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=myFile, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

    MsgBox "PDF version of report has been created."
End If

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub
```

I've already tried replacing the "Set ws = ActiveSheet" to "Selection", and that has yielded no results. Also, as a side note, when selections are sent to a PDF, they appear on separate sheets.Is it possible to put them both on one sheet?

Thanks in advance for any help that you can offer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the [Print Area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839804.aspx) that you want to output to PDF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only problem with this is that it will be a different area each time, so having to change the code each time wouldn't be ideal. Do you know if it's possible to export my manual selections without changing the code?

Comment: You can dynamically set those ranges, depending on what you want to export. `Dim exportRange as Range` and `Set exportRange = ActiveSheet.Selection` type of statements.